# How to monitor streaming servers

Tags: linux, bandwidth, lighttpd, streaming, monitoring

I have had a bunch of Linux based streaming servers that employed lighttpd web server to provide video streaming via port 80.

Recently, our service is very slow. Therefore, I would like to ask if there is a good software package that helps us monitor and record our bandwidth usage, lighttpd established connections, TCP sync connections, disk I/O ... over time.

Any suggestions?

Regards,

Dinh

Answer (score 1):

[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) - for graphing historic data

[Hyperic](http://www.hyperic.com/) - clunky, but has good auto discovery and integration via is agent

[Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/) - open source competitor to Hyperic

[Munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) - UNIX Style monitoring toolkit, similar to Cacti, in the spirit of MRTG

[Collectd](http://collectd.org/) - Another stats collection daemon, you'll need to integrate it with something else to produce your statistics.

Comment: also, nagios and opennms

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/)